# XML Schema: Referenced attribute is missing

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

When validating the the following XML against the schema, the reference attributes of KeyB are marked as missing/undeclared unless prefixed with a namespace. Similar attributes for KeyA, which are declared "inline", validate fine. Can someone explain this to me? (Note: Using .NET's XmlReader for validation).

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="so"
    targetNamespace="http://test/so.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://test/so.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
  <xs:attribute name="Index" type="xs:unsignedByte" />

  <xs:element name="KeyA">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="Index" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="KeyB">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute ref="Id" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute ref="Index" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>


  <xs:element name="Keys">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="KeyA"/>
        <xs:element ref="KeyB"/>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

XML instance example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Keys xmlns="http://test/so.xsd">
  <KeyA Id="0" Index="3"/>
  <KeyB Id="0" Index="3"/>
</Keys>
```

I receive the following error messages for the KeyB element:

```
The required attribute 'http://test/so.xsd:Index' is missing.
The required attribute 'http://test/so.xsd:Id' is missing.

The 'Index' attribute is not declared.
The 'Id' attribute is not declared.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's easy.

The **local attributes** (that's what you call *declared "inline"*) may be qualified and may be not. "Qualified" roughly means that the namespace prefix will be required.

This is controlled by the `attributeFormDefault` attribute of your `<xs:schema>`.
If you had specified:

```
<xs:schema id="so"
    targetNamespace="http://test/so.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://test/so.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

....
```

then, all local attributes would have to be qualified.

But by default, the value of `attributeFormDefault` is `"unqualified"`.
So, when you miss it, you have all local attributes unqualified (no namespace prefix needed).

Concerning **global attributes** (and only them you can include by reference),
they must **always** be **qualified**.
That's actually the rule for anything declared globally (and elements as well).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I was missing the implications of the attributes being declared globally.